# Using Raspberry Pi and Mono to use a SDK built for Windows?

Tags: c#, dll, mono, raspberry-pi

So here is the deal, I was using a sdk from a company named ZKTeco. It is used to communicate with a fingerprint reading device.

The sdk contains some .dll that have to be installed on Windows (@System32) in order to work, as well as a Interop dll used to create C# code with the SDK.

The problem is, I'm trying to use it on a Raspberry pi running Raspbian Lite. When I built the most basic C# application on Mono, where I would just instantiate the class coming from the SDK, I get the following error:

> System.DllNotFoundException: ole32.dll

Witch is a native .dll from window.

I do not have access to the source code. Is there any workaround for this situation? Or should I give up on making it work?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: If that dll is built for Windows. It will not run on your Raspbian os, you need to check with the provider of your SDK to see if they have an alternative.

Comment: If a dll was compiled for x86/x64 it won't work on ARM processors.